# INSERT после SELECT в одном запросе

Tags: mysql, sql

В SQL я новичок, меня интересует, возможно ли в одном запросе выполнить конструкцию `INSERT` после `SELECT`?

Comment: а что вы собственно хотите этим добиться?

Answer (score 2):

Почти во всех современных база данных вы можете воспользоваться оператором `INSERT ... SELECT ...`, позволяющим вставлять в таблицу результаты выборки оператором `SELECT`

```
INSERT INTO
  tab1
SELECT
  *
FROM
  tab2
```

Comment: Это да, но мне нужно реализовать конструкцию типа SELECT tab1 FROM table UNION INSERT INTO

Comment: @FilippMustang, тогда смотрите в сторону триггеров - хранимых функций, которые срабатывают на каждую вставку или обновление данных.

Comment: @FilippMustang А что по вашему мнению должен был бы выполнить запрос select union insert если бы он был возможен ?

Comment: Есть такие вещи, как sql-инъекции. Сделать два запроса возможности нету. Конечной целью является изменение данных в таблице с запроса начинающего с SELECT'а.

Answer (score 0):

например у нас есть запрос вида

`"SELECT * FROM news WHERE id_news = $id"`

мы можем передать  туда что типо 

`666;INSERT INTO user(username, password) VALUES ('i', '777');`

 и получим две команды

`SELECT * FROM news WHERE id_news = 666;
INSERT INTO user(username, password) VALUES ('i', '777');`

Comment: Такой подход работал примерно до 2008 года. Обычно стоят ограничения, можно выполнять только один запрос за раз.